# Enabled property of QML widget blocked by attached action

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I want to enable button when `TextField` has acceptable text (I'm using the `validator`), and this code is working fine:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 100
    id: mainWindow
    property int _buttonSize: 30
    property int _interval: 10

    TextField {
        y: _interval
        width: parent.width
        height: _buttonSize
        id: ipInput
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        placeholderText: "IP"
        validator: RegExpValidator
        {
            regExp:/^(([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.){3}([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$/
        }
    }

    Button {
        enabled: ipInput.acceptableInput
        id: go
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        y: ipInput.y+_buttonSize+_interval
        width: parent.width
        height: _buttonSize
        text: "GO"
    }
}
```

So, I add the `Action` to this `Button`:

```
Button {
    enabled: ipInput.acceptableInput
    id: go
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    y: ipInput.y+_buttonSize+_interval
    width: parent.width
    height: _buttonSize
    text: "GO"
    action: goAction
    Action {
        id: goAction
        shortcut: "Enter"
        enabled: go.enabled && go.visible
        onTriggered: {
            console.log("good")
        }
    }
}
```

And now the `Button` is always disabled. How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Action`s work by *synchronising* the state of all the `Item`s to which they are bound. The documentation says:

> In applications many common commands can be invoked via menus, toolbar buttons, and keyboard shortcuts. Since the user expects **each command to be performed in the same way**, regardless of the user interface used, it is useful to represent each command as an action.
>
> **An action can be bound to a menu item and a toolbar button, and it will automatically keep them in sync**. For example, in a word processor, if the user presses a Bold toolbar button, the Bold menu item will automatically be checked.

In this sense, the `Action` properties *rules over* the properties of the `Item`s to which it is bound and not the vice versa. When the `Action` is enabled also *all* the `Item`s to which it is attached, are enabled. Hence, the enabling condition should be moved to the `Action`.

Here is a revisited version of your code. I've added another `Button` to stress the `Action` functionality. Here both the `Button`s automatically enables when the condition is met, since it's the associated `Action` to become enabled.

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    id: mainWindow

    Column {
        spacing: 10
        TextField {
            width: 400
            height: 40
            id: ipInput
            horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter
            placeholderText: "IP"
            validator: RegExpValidator {
                regExp:/^(([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.){3}([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$/
            }
        }

        Action {
            id: goAction
            shortcut: "Enter"
            enabled: ipInput.acceptableInput
            onTriggered: {
                console.log("good")
            }
        }

        Button {
            id: go
            width: 400
            height: 40
            text: "GO"
            action: goAction
        }

        Button {
            id: go2
            width: 400
            height: 40
            text: "GO2"
            action: goAction
        }
    }
}
```